# UISlider Producing Bizarre Values

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uislider

I have a UISlider which I'd like to allow a selection between 0.5 and 10. When the callback is fired to set the value of a label when the value changes, I get a strange range of values. The code I have is:

```
-(IBAction)DidChangeSliderValue:(id)sender {
    NSString *distance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i miles", sdrDistance.value];
    lblDistance.text = distance;
    NSLog(distance);
```

I have the slider set up as follows:
[image: Slider Setup]

However, dragging from left to right results in this to the log:

```
1-07-12 16:38:24.354 myapp[2758:207] 1073741824 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:24.355 myapp[2758:207] 0 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:24.356 myapp[2758:207] 0 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:27.873 myapp[2758:207] 0 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:27.890 myapp[2758:207] -1073741824 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:27.924 myapp[2758:207] -2147483648 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:27.941 myapp[2758:207] 536870912 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:27.957 myapp[2758:207] -2147483648 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:27.991 myapp[2758:207] 1073741824 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:28.007 myapp[2758:207] -536870912 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:28.023 myapp[2758:207] 1073741824 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:28.041 myapp[2758:207] 536870912 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:28.058 myapp[2758:207] -536870912 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:28.074 myapp[2758:207] 1073741824 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:28.091 myapp[2758:207] 536870912 miles
2011-07-12 16:38:28.141 myapp[2758:207] 0 miles
```

Is there any logical reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UISlider value]` returns a `float`, not an `int`, so you have to use `%f` instead of `%i` in your NSLog statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` is a float. Use `%f` instead of `%i`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an int (%i) to a float value (%f) because a uislider is a float (decimals) not an int (whole number) So it should be this:

```
-(IBAction)DidChangeSliderValue:(id)sender {
NSString *distance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f miles", sdrDistance.value];
lblDistance.text = distance;
NSLog(distance);
```